# How do I copy object data with deformation animations with AN?

Tags: animation, armature, animation-nodes

I created this setup for instancing and copying deformed mesh with its armature animation but all I see is the non deformed mesh of cyclinder.

Is it possible to instance and copy meshes while keeping their armature deformed animations in this kind of setup?

You can download the blender file from here

https://quickfileshare.org/2hMH/copy_dformed_30092020_2107_08.zip

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mesh replicating using `Transform Mesh` node.

[image]

[image]

Another Non intuitive way, Here armatures and objects are instanced and each armature is set to appropriate objects. For some reason it was not updating as expected. so i used an expression to force reset data. It also caused performance drop :(

[image]

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the reply. This solves the issue in a different way, while it is great, is there a way to do it without bringing the armature st uff into the conversation? I want to resolve this in mesh level inside AN. Because I actually have many seed objects with many armatures in the original setup

Comment: @yaruncan Armature is currently in (10,0,0) to remove that offset in replicants i subtracted it. You can remove that node and manually add vectors or set armature location to (0,0,0).

Comment: Hari I have been using the Mesh Object Output solution but the issue is that those new objects are not linked copies :( Is there a way to clone the data using the Copy Object Data node like approach?